# Quick benchmark from the command line

Tags: php, bash, benchmarking

I'd like to benchmark a PHP script, but this would equally apply to anything that can be run from the command line.

Using bash is there a simple way to benchmark a script, i.e. run a command multiple times and time how long it takes?

Comment: Hold on, would this be better on SU? I think I'm ok actually faq: 'software tools commonly used by programmers'

Comment: Yea post it on SU. Segregate our community more.

Comment: SU is definitely more suitable for this question, but to basically answer the question, I think you are probably looking for [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

Comment: Apache Bench (ab) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: @rgvcorley also check out [LTTng](http://lttng.org/)

Comment: How about using good ol' [`times`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In command line, you can:

```
$ time php foobar.php
```

Here `time` is a bash built-in.

For multiple runs:

```
$ time for a in {1..10}; do php foobar.php; done
real    0m13.042s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.044s
```

However, you need to calculate the average time by hand.

Comment: `perf stat -r10 php foobar.php` will run it 10 times and average + stddev for you, at least for the "task-clock" CPU time.  (Not necessarily wall-clock time, which can differ if you block on I/O or use multiple cores at once.)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to benchmark a PHP script why not just write a unit test for it. Like:

```
<?php

function test() {
    require 'my_script_to_test.php';
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $time = microtime(true);
    test();
    $time = microtime(true) - $time;
    echo 'test '.$i.': '.$time;
    // and then you can also average time and w/e 
}

?>
```

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the OP question

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Xiè Jìléi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11555395/986896), if one does not want to calculate average by hand:

```
: > benchmark.tmp
for i in {1..10} ; do \
    /usr/bin/time --output benchmark.tmp --append --format "%e" -- custom-cmd-for-benchmark ; \
done
awk '{ total += $1; count++ } END { print total/count }' benchmark.tmp
```

or oneliner:

```
RETRIES=10 ; CMD="custom-cmd-for-benchmark"; /usr/bin/time --output benchmark.tmp --format "%e" -- bash -c "for i in {1..${RETRIES}} ; do ${CMD} ; done" ; awk "{ print \$1/${RETRIES} }" benchmark.tmp
```

NOTE: `{1..10}` defines number of retires

NOTE2: this is not using bash built-in `time` for better control over output stream (in case `custom-cmd-for-benchmark` outputs something)!

WARNING: this overrides `benchmark.tmp` file!

Other ideas (for better precision, but drop std output, which may bias benchmark, as writing to `/dev/null` may be faster than to terminal):

```
# This using bash built-in + TIMEFORMAT variable
( export TIMEFORMAT='%3R' ; time for i in {1..10} ; do custom-cmd-for-benchmark >/dev/null ; done ) 2>&1 | awk '{ print $1/10 }'

# This using `date` tool
( date +'%s.%N' | tr -d "\n"; for i in {1..10} ; do custom-cmd-for-benchmark >/dev/null ; done ; date +' %s.%N' ) | awk '{ printf "%.4f",($2 - $1)/10 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're just looking for php[BogoMips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips),

```
$ time php -r 'for($outer=0;$outer<10;++$outer){$t=microtime(true);for($i=0;$i<10000000;++$i){}$t=microtime(true)-$t;$phpBogoMips=10/$t;echo "phpBogoMips: ",$phpBogoMips,PHP_EOL;}'
phpBogoMips: 66.581855298938
phpBogoMips: 74.053284839068
phpBogoMips: 75.23266805498
phpBogoMips: 113.19650341535
phpBogoMips: 84.938811631359
phpBogoMips: 102.55999960876
phpBogoMips: 103.25660631902
phpBogoMips: 84.562239668388
phpBogoMips: 77.247435401588
phpBogoMips: 78.314767444032

real    0m1.307s
user    0m1.124s
sys     0m0.078s
```

- it counts how many times per second PHP can count to 1 million..
- the wide variation here <s>can probably  attributed to me running it on a laptop-on-battery?</s> is because i ran it on a laptop on battery. screenshot on dedicated servers with more consistent results (the left-most is the laptop, and it shows): https://i.stack.imgur.com/c47EP.png
- <s>someone should doube-check my math here, i'm not 100% certain i got it right.</s> - someone did! the math seems about right.